# Reset password for Azure virtual machine

Tags: ssh, virtual-machines, azure

I forgot my user account to log in to my Azure Virtual Machine. From the new portal I tried the option "Reset password" entering a new user and password. However, I get the notification:

```
Failed to reset the password/ssh key for virtual machine 'EXAMPLE'.
```

If I click on "Reset Remote Access" I get error:

```
Failed to reset the SSH configuration for virtual machine 'EXAMPLE'.
```

I added a new user `me@gmail.com` (Microsoft user) as owner, but if I do `ssh example.cloudapp.net -l me@gmail.com` with my Microsoft password I am not granted access.

What can I do?

Comment: Download the vhd and attach it to a local vm, boot to a rescue cd. That should work.

Answer (score 1):

To use reset password feature on Linux VM, you need to have a Linux VM with Microsoft Azure Linux Agent version 2.0.6 or later.

Note most Azure VM Linux gallery images included version 2.0.6 above.

All step by step operation to reset Linux credential through this agent are detailled here :
https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/blog/using-vmaccess-extension-to-reset-login-credentials-for-linux-vm/

Regards